# Can I use the Auth0 sdk with stateful components?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, single-page-application, auth0

The auth0 react quickstart guide features a only functional components, but I have a need for stateful, class components.

However, with this, I can't seem to either access user profile data, or access authentication tokens, because those are called with React hooks.

Does anyone know how to configure the auth0 react sdk so that I can access this data in a stateful, class based component?

Thanks!